# xlop inconsistent display style when multiplying numbers that end in 0 (multiples of 10)

Tags: tex-core, xlop

I am using xlop to generate some math worksheets but when multiplying numbers like 
    `{70 * 10 }`
xlop is showing just one step and that looks inconsistent to kids and alignment of problems is off. Is there a way to solve this?

here is my code

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{xlop}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},before*=\small,leftmargin=*,itemsep=1.00cm, labelsep=0.0cm]
            \item {\opmul[style=display, voperation=center] {70}{10} }
            \item {\opmul[style=display, voperation=center] {71}{11} }
            \item {\opmul[style=display, voperation=center] {72}{12} }
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Output produced is this 
[image: see single line output for first problem]

I'd like to see this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-display of the zero intermediate numbers is due to the default value of the `displayintermediary` parameter. The value `all` will display all the intermediate numbers.

```
  \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{xlop}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},before*=\small,leftmargin=*,itemsep=1.00cm, labelsep=0.0cm]
            \item {\opmul[style=display, voperation=center,displayintermediary=all] {70}{10} }
            \item {\opmul[style=display, voperation=center] {71}{11} }
            \item {\opmul[style=display, voperation=center] {72}{12} }
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image: xlop displayintermediary]